# MoveGroup init object issue

Tags: ros, moveit, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Moveit there is the `MoveGroup` class used to control a group of links and joints.
In official tutorial is showed an initialization of the object in the main like:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
```

I would like to create a service call, which executes some movement of the arm.
How can I create/initialize the `MoveGroup` object such that it is visible (e.g. as global variable) to the service callback function and also visible for other functions?
The constructor of the `MoveGroup` is defined like this:

```
/** \brief Construct a client for the MoveGroup action using a specified set of options \e opt. Optionally, specify a TF instance to use. If not specified, one will be constructed internally. A timeout for connecting to the action server can also be specified. If it is not specified, the wait time is unlimited. */
  MoveGroup(const Options &opt, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> &tf = boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>(), const ros::Duration &wait_for_server = ros::Duration(0, 0));

  /** \brief Construct a client for the MoveGroup action for a particular \e group. Optionally, specify a TF instance to use. If not specified, one will be constructed internally. A timeout for connecting to the action server can also be specified. If it is not specified,   the wait time is unlimited. */
  MoveGroup(const std::string &group, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> &tf = boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>(), const ros::Duration &wait_for_server = ros::Duration(0, 0));
```

I also tired to create my own class that has a `MoveGroup` argument, but I couldn't initialize in the constructor like:

```
group = new moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup("arm");
```

Error at build is:

```
/home/elod/catkin_ws/src/arm_control/arm_action_server/src/main.cpp:36:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::MoveGroup()’
 moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group;
                                       ^
/home/elod/catkin_ws/src/arm_control/arm_action_server/src/main.cpp:36:39: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/arm_control/arm_action_server/src/main.cpp:9:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:122:3: note: moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::MoveGroup(const string&, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>&, const ros::Duration&)
   MoveGroup(const std::string &group, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> &tf = boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>(),
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:122:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:116:3: note: moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::MoveGroup(const moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Options&, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>&, const ros::Duration&)
   MoveGroup(const Options &opt, const boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> &tf = boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer>(),
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:116:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
In file included from /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/arm_control/arm_action_server/src/main.cpp:9:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:69:7: note: moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::MoveGroup(const moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup&)
 class MoveGroup
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:69:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/arm_action.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/arm_action.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217959/movegroup-init-object-issue/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a solution I implemented after reading several post online. It is working.

```
class ArmControl {
public:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    string planning_group_name_;
    double POS_TOLARENCE, ANG_TOLARENCE, PLANING_TIME;
    // interface with MoveIt
    boost::scoped_ptr<move_group_interface::MoveGroup> move_group_;
    ArmControl::ArmControl() :
        nh_("~"),
        planning_group_name_("arm"),
        POS_TOLARENCE(0.01),
        ANG_TOLARENCE(0.1),
        PLANING_TIME(20.0) 
    {
    move_group_.reset(
            new move_group_interface::MoveGroup(planning_group_name_));
    move_group_->setPlanningTime(PLANING_TIME);
    move_group_->setGoalOrientationTolerance(ANG_TOLARENCE);
    move_group_->setGoalPositionTolerance(POS_TOLARENCE);
    sleep(5);
   }
  }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "arm_action_server");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(0);
    spinner.start();

    ArmControl controller;      
    controller.moveToInitialPos();    
    ros::ServiceServer findCB_service = nh.advertiseService("find_chess_board",
                    &ArmControl::findCB, &controller);    
    ros::ServiceServer flippSW_service = nh.advertiseService("flipp_switch",
                        &ArmControl::flippSW, &controller);
    ros::waitForShutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2015-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mony.khosravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31130/mony.khosravi/) on 2017-12-04**:
Many thanks. It also solved my problem.